# Can I convert an array of bytes in a SQL Server varbinary column into a string using pure SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode, encoding

I have a string, which I am converting into an array at bytes, via Unicode, in C#:

```
var myString = "Hello World!";
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myString)
```

I'm then inserting this into a varbinary column in SQL Server:

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data (value) VALUES (@value)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", bytes);
```

So, in the "value" column, I have an array of bytes, encoded in C# via Unicode.

Is there any way to decode this purely in SQL, rather than pull it out and decode it in C#?  I'd like to use the text value in SQL in some instances, and I don't want to have to take it back to C# first.

**EDIT:**

I attempted this:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(NVarChar(40), value) FROM Data
```

However, the result was some type of Asian-looking string (looked like Kanji), which tells me the encoding is off.

**RESOLUTION**

I'm an idiot. Further digging produced the actual C# code...

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString)
```

Trying to decode that in SQL does not work -- that which is encoded in ASCII cannot be decoded via Unicode(-ish).

Comment: how about a google search on the following [sql convert varbinary to string](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20convert%20varbinary%20to%20string) lots of examples on line check out the link

Comment: I had tried that already. I edited the question to note that.

Comment: sounds like could be `encoding issue` or Casting issue vs Convert take a look at the following it may help shed some light http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: `CONVERT(NVarChar` should work; `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x480065006C006C006F00)` should he `Hello`

Comment: Does it default to Unicode when converting?

Comment: SQL Server? It will use UCS-2 for the conversion which is the same in terms of codepoints as the UTF-16 your using from C#

Comment: Let me dig in my code. Perhaps I'm encoding it wrong...

Comment: I'm an idiot. Question updated with resolution.

Comment: So did casting to `varchar` instead work?

Comment: No, it had nothing to do with the type. It was encoding it as ASCII and trying to decode as Unicode -- that was the problem.

Comment: @Deane - So casting it to `varchar` should have worked then as it doesn't try to decode as unicode. Though if the contents are text they should just be stored as text. There is no benefit of storing as binary.

Comment: Perhaps. I never tried it.